# Pandas - new dataframe with the difference from two previous dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes, "Status" which is an excel file where somebody changes dates manually every week, and "Default" which contains the last week "Status" data.
I'm releasing an alert from every change in the Status file, from which I extract the data with the following code:

```
Status = pd.concat([Status,Default]).reset_index(drop=True)
Status = Status.drop_duplicates(keep=False, subset=Status.columns.difference(["Filename"]),ignore_index=False) # Filename can have "Status" or Default".
Status = Status[~Status["Filename"].isin(["Status"])]
Status = Status.merge(Default,  how="cross", suffixes("A","B"))

Status["Diff"] = np.where(Status["DateA" == Status["DateB"],1,0)

Status = Status[Status["Diff"]==1]
```

The problem is that when somebody loads a new row (which means that Default doesn't contain it) it is not getting returned. I'm only sending data that was previously loaded. Also, the table has the following format:

| Client | Opp | Date | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | 1/07/2022 | Test1 |
| One | Two | 5/08/2022 | Test2 |
| Two | Four | 3/03/2023 | Test3 |
| Three | Five | 1/01/2023 | Test4 |

How can I proceed?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: Also, I forgot to mention that I need to add the previous date (the one that was replaced) in the alert.

Comment: Hmm this could definitely work, but how can I link the previous date (the one that was replaced) with the new one?

Comment: Ok so the final output is this:
Client: One
Opp: Two
Previous Date: 1/06/2022 (suppose)
Date: 1/07/2022
Description: Test1

This is sent in a email with python smtplib.